# laravel Only one usage of each socket address

Tags: laravel-5

i am getting this error a lot lately idk why and i searched but couldnt finda  solution

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1)